# Does Kotlin Flow Emits new data every time if something changed in room database?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

Let's Say Here is Sample Code

**LiveData Query**

```
Query("SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(id),0) FROM Item WHERE status = :status")
fun getLiveData(status: Int): LiveData<Int>
```

**Kotlin Flow Query**

```
@Query("SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(id),0) FROM Item WHERE status = :status")
fun getFlowData(status: Int): Flow<Int>
```

So my Question is Flow gets new data if anything changes in the room database?

Comment: Yes. Similar to a `LiveData`, a `Flow` will emit data whenever a change happens in the underlying database. The difference is you have to handle the lifecycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Flow emits new data if anything changes in the room database, like the example below:

```
val flow = getFlowData(2) // type Flow<Int>
flow.collect { data ->
    // every time anything changes, the code inside collect is going to get called again
}
```

and also there is `.first()` that will give you only the latest emitted data without live changes:

```
val data = getFlowData(2).first() // type Int
```

So it depends on how you are using Flow, and it depends on your needs.